# How can I export user_Id to OMS Log Analytics from Application Insights?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

The application insights data contains 'user_id'. When connecting the application insights to OMS Log Analytics the 'user_id' information is missing.

Is it possible to get the 'user_id' across?

I've also tried supplying the 'user id' through customDimension properties but no luck.
Would appreciate any guidance. Thank you.